# GradBagLayout not distributing columns based on weight

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is what my GUI looks like now:
[image]

I want it to have the three columns to be equally distributed. To do this, I set each of the weights equal to 1/3. Obviously, it's not working.

Here is my code for creating the Frame:

```
public static JPanel createLayout(int rows) {
    JPanel product = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    String[] lables = {"School    ", "Advanced #", "Novice #   "};
    double weight = .3333333333333;

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    c.weightx = weight;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridy = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < lables.length; j++) {
        c.gridx = j;
        JLabel l = new JLabel(lables[j]);
        product.add(l, c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        c.gridy++;
        for (int j = 0; j < lables.length; j++) {
            c.gridx = j;
            JTextField f = new JTextField();
            product.add(f, c);
        }
    }
    c.gridy++;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    JPanel b = new JPanel();
    JButton add = new JButton("+");
    b.add(add);
    JButton delete = new JButton("-");
    b.add(delete);
    product.add(b, c);
    return product;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debate Calculator");
    JPanel debates = new JPanel();
    frame.add(createLayout(5), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you components are not equally sized to begin with. I can't explain exactly why it does what it does, but the size of your labels is each different because they have a different number of characters. I know you tried to make then the same size, but a " " is not the same as "W".

I changed your code to use the following and it seems to work:

```
JTextField f = new JTextField(10);
```

Now the width of each text field is greater than the label, so that is the width that is used to give each column a proportional size.

You might consider using a GridLayout. The default behaviour is to make each cell the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your button bar at the bottom.  Set the gridwidth to REMAINDER on that element.